# Understanding a recursive function for generating permutations of a sequence

Tags: python, recursion

I've been trying to get my head around recursive functions when I came across a query on the python tutor mailing list that I found interesting.

As a general question I am trying to understand how a function can call itself before returning a value? How does that function "know what to do" (i.e. what value(s) to return) if it calls itself before the end of the body (which is an implicit return None if no return statement exists).

On the the specific questions, this email thread I noticed had the following function (which I've modified) but am having some issues with.

```
def perms(items):
    """ Recursive function that uses a generator object
        to compute all permutations of a given set of strings """
    ## CALL: list(perms("abc"))
    boolarr = [(i == items[0]) for i in items if (len(items) > 1)] 
    if False not in boolarr:
        print "%s" %("no permutations exist") 
        yield items
    elif not items:
        yield []
    elif (len(items) == 1):
        yield items[0]
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            ## find permutations of everything except items[i]
            for j in perms(items[:i] + items[(i+1):]):
            ## add items[i] to each of those permutations 
                yield items[i] + j
    return
```

When I call this function from the interpreter as list(perms("abc")), I get the following output:

```
no permutations exist
no permutations exist
no permutations exist
no permutations exist
no permutations exist
no permutations exist
Out[477]: ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

I have written the boolean array on the first line to create an array of True values for strings with the same character, e.g. ["a","a","a'] returns ["True", "True", "True" ] so why is it evaluating list("abc") as such when it should be populated with False values after the first value, which by construction is True. I have tested this on the interpreter and found it works.

Also, why is it printing the string multiple times as if it is part of a loop? The way the function is written it should only go to the nested iteration if the sequence that is input by the user is LONGER than 2 characters AND it is not composed of all identical characters. If I comment the print line after the first conditional in the body the function works, I just don't understand why.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think you have a bit of a misconception about when recursive functions return. Try putting some print statements in, that might help to resolve your confusion.

Comment: @Daniel: Thank you, aren't the *yield* statements more or less doing what print would have done? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No, not at all. Printing would be to help *you* understand what lines are being executed in what order.

Comment: Please search before posting.  There are quite a few questions with good answers in this very forum that explain how recursive functions operate.  Some of them deal with this very application to permutations.